# How to perform bulk updates in Solr

Tags: solr

Is there a way in Solr to perform bulk updates without specifying it document by document?

In Solr we can update a field of a single record at a time, But in order to update the 1000 record it's gonna take more time . So any option is there to update a field of thousand indexes in a shot or in a one go ?

Comment: This one liner statement does not give any idea...could you be more descriptive?

Comment: In Solr we can update a field of a single record at a time, But in order to update the 1000 record it's gonna take more time . So any option is there to update a field of thousand indexes in a shot or in a one go ?

Answer (score 7):

No, there is nothing similar to `UPDATE foo SET field = "bar"` - you'll have to either submit the complete set of updated documents, or a batches of atomic update commands (each related to a separate id).

```
[{"id":"mydoc", "price":{"set":99}}, 
 {"id":"mydoc2", "price":{"set":199}}]
```

Comment: Thnaks for the reply !