# How to update a single field value in multiple solr docs

Tags: solr

i have an issue with solr. i have to update a single field value in multiple solr docs, like we update on DB "update customer set country='India' where city='Delhi'"

"docs": [
      {
        "classId": "23003",
        "status": 1,
        "notificationId": 27057,
        "isRead": 0
      },
      {
        "classId": "23003",
        "status": 1,
        "notificationId": 42001,
        "isRead": 0
      },
      {
        "classId": "23003",
        "status": 1,
        "notificationId": 27060,
        "isRead": 0
      },
      {
        "classId": "62277",
        "status": 1,
        "notificationId": 72327,
        "isRead": 0
      }
    ]

i have to update status = 0, where classId=23003.

Please help me how can i do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform bulk updates in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372899/how-to-perform-bulk-updates-in-solr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, updating multiple documents in a single request is not supported in Solr.

You'll have to retrieve the list of documents (i.e query for `city:Delhi`), then issue an atomic update for each one:

```
[
    {"notificationId":"retrievedId1", "status":{"set": 0}}, 
    {"notificationId":"retrievedId2", "status":{"set": 0}}, 
]
```

Include [the `_version_` parameter from each document to avoid overwriting changes](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-OptimisticConcurrency) made by other threads in the meantime (optimistic concurrency) if necessary.

Comment: thanks, there is one more issue. after this i have to commit again manuly to get changes on solr, is there any way to commit auto after update

Comment: Use `commitWithin` - it'll tell Solr to issue a commit at least within x number of milliseconds after the update request. That way you'll be sure to get your changes visible within a certain time, and you can still issue many requests without having to commit after each one.